# Cannot restore Windows Backup Image made in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, uefi, gpt, windows-backup

I have the following Situation:

- Laptop is EliteBook 840G1 with 256 GB SSD (Crucial M550).
- Windows 8.1 with Update has been installed without CSM.
- I made a Backup using Windows' System Image Backup on an external HDD. (it made an Image of 3 Partitions: EFI, MSR and Drive C)
- I created a USB Recovery drive using the Control Panel.
- After replacing the SSD with 250 GB (Crucial MX200), I booted up from mentioned USB Stick and started the System Image Recovery.

But the process always stops and tells that there is no Drive available to make a Recovery to. But the new SSD is visible inside WinRE, I installed the RST drivers, I even manually converted it to a GPT drive, with no partitions, but still no hope.

Any solutions or suggestions?

PS: I found [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744301(v=ws.10).aspx) but I don't know, why give option for System Image if I still must create Partitions myself. (And I don't remember the EFI and MSR Partition size on the backed up Image) Back on Windows 7, I could restore whole (MBR) drive without any trouble

Answer (score 0):

Windows Image Backup is very fussy about restoring to a drive that is not the one used for creating the image. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. A roll of the dice.
Try using a cloning software instead, to clone the original drive to the new one. This usually works. I have used the freeware program, "Drive Clone" from Farstone with success.

Comment: as I guessed. Any way to restore the Image via another Application? I have a 30 GB Image (vhdx) right now.

Comment: [Storage Craft says their software can do it](https://www.storagecraft.com/support/book/storagecraft-recovery-environment-user-guide/restoring-system-volume)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Image Backup is specific to that operating system and program. No other software will be able to read that image.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed back the old SSD and used the System Image Recovery successfully.
So Windows Image Backup really doesn't like if the destination drive is smaller than the original one, even if the original drive was never full. (Image was 30 GB)
Then I connected both SSDs to my Desktop PC and used Acronis True Image and cloned them. Worked without any hassle.
Conclusion: If your new drive is smaller than the old one, DON'T use Windows Image Backup